# How to only allow users to a page through a rewrite?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website where I am using SSI to include some stuff to the front page. However, I'd like to show users an URL that ends with `.html`. I have accomplished that via a `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.shtml [PT,L]
```

Also, I am using another redirect pointing to this URL to internally load the pages' content with JavaScript (`example.html` to `index.html#example.html`) with a condition for not redirecting `index.html`.

Now, I'd like to make the `.shtml` page `403 Forbidden`. This is also easy:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.shtml - [F]
```

But, now `index.html` also gets forbidden.

I have tried adding `L` to the `.html`-to-`.shtml` rule, but this doesn't help. How could this problem be solved?

**EDIT:** Here's my complete `.htaccess` file with the thing anubhava suggested.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /subdir/notfound.html
ErrorDocument 500 /subdir/internalerror.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|notfound\.html|internalerror\.html)(#.*)?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*\.html)$ /subdir/index.html#$1 [R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.shtml [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.shtml
RewriteRule ^index\.shtml - [F]
```

And my directory structure:

```
/public_html
|
+-- subdir
    |
    +-- .htaccess
    |
    +-- index.shtml
    |
    +-- notfound.html
    |
    +-- internalerror.html
    |
    +-- style.css
    |
    +-- script.js
    |
    +-- ajax-pages
        |
        +-- index.html
        |
        +-- foo.html
        |
        +-- bar.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule with `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.shtml [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Problem with your rule is that `index.html` get rewritten to `index.shtml` and Apache re-injects rewritten URI for further rule evaluation and Apache issues Forbidden error for `index.html` also.

**Complete .htaccess:**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /subdir/notfound.html
ErrorDocument 500 /subdir/internalerror.html

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.shtml [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.shtml - [F]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.shtml [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(index\.s?html|notfound\.html|internalerror\.html) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*\.html)$ /subdir/index.html#$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't `L` mean the URL does not get rewritten anymore?

Comment: No that's not correct `L` just injects URI back for rule evaluation.

Comment: OK. There is still a problems. This does not work if the file is in a subdirectory (my case).

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.shtml [NC]` should work even from subdirectory. Can you post your complete .htaccess so that I can investigate and suggest.

Comment: Can you provide some details about SSI issue. How it is done and what problem are you facing?

Comment: I have an SSI comment: `<!-- #include virtual="ajax-pages/index.html" -->` as I'd like to only update the main page's content once when updating. This does not run; the comment can be found when viewing the page's source at client-side. Also, I can confirm that this worked before I started messing around with the rewrites.

Comment: Yeah, this stuff sometimes... It was fixed by removing _the single space_ between `<!--` and `#include`. Dreamweaver wasn't removing its code coloring for the comment, so I thought it wouldn't be a problem. Thanks for all the help!